# ignore a match of 3 for a match of 4 or 5

Tags: c++

I'm working on a Bejeweled like game for a data structures class. It's been years since I've taken intro to C++ and my logic is quite rusty.

My code recognizes a match of 4 as two matches of 3. I'm not sure how to bypass the match of 3 for the match of 4. I've tried an if statement like `if (counter = 3 && board[y][x] == board[y][x-1])`, but it didn't work out the way I intended.

Here is my code:

```
// Counts the number of matches (3 or more)
// returns number of matches found
int CountJewels(){
int matches = 0;

// Horizontal jewels
for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
    int counter = 1;
    for (int x = 1; x < size; x++){
        if (board[y][x] == board[y][x-1]){
            counter++;
            if (counter >= 3){
                matches++;
            }
        } else  {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
}

// Vertical jewels
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
    int counter = 1;
    for(int y = 1; y < size; y++){
        if(board[y][x] == board[y-1][x]){
            counter++;
            if (counter >= 3){
                matches++;
            }
        } else  {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
}
cout << matches << endl;
return matches;
}
```

Comment: Well, there is also the case of horizontal and vertical line sharing a cell. (It would belong to a new question if you want to take care of such case, though).

Answer (score 2):

Very simple. Just change the condition to `counter == 3`. A match of 3 or more will be recognized as a single match, since you only count once when the number of consecutive matching cells is >= 3.

Answer (score 1):

One idea can be not to increase the matches directly, but just to increase the count number in same jewels. Finally, when a non-same character is found, if you have a count greater than 2, then count it as one match:

```
//Counts the number of matches (3 or more)
// returns number of matches found
int CountJewels(){
int matches = 0;

// Horizontal jewels
for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
    int counter = 1;
    for (int x = 1; x < size; x++){
        if (board[y][x] == board[y][x-1]){
            counter++;
        } else  {
            //Check if there was a matching before the mismatch.
            if(counter > 2){
              matches++;
            }
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    //Checking last cell matches.
    if(counter > 2){
        matches++;
    }
}

//Vertical jewels
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
    int counter = 1;
    for(int y = 1; y < size; y++){
        if(board[y][x] == board[y-1][x]){
            counter++;
        } else  {
            //Check if there was a matching before the mismatch.
            if(counter > 2){
              matches++;
            }
            counter = 1;
        }

    }
    //Checking last cell matches.
    if(counter > 2){
        matches++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to fix it for cases where the match is at the end.

Comment: It would be easier to move the last `if(counter>2)matches++` *after* the inner loop.

Comment: Right, no need for constant checking in second loop.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. (counter is reset in first loop). Fixed now.

Comment: Now drop the superfluous test for the no-longer-existing `x` and you are good :)

Comment: Why on earth was I checking for x and y in the outter loops? Ah, I need rest and more learning and programming....Thanks for helping on the answer! I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
// Horizontal jewels
for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
    int counter = 1;
    for (int x = 1; x < size; x++){
        if (board[y][x] == board[y][x-1]){
            counter++;
        } else  {
            foundAlignmentOf(counter);
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    foundAlignmentOf(counter); // Or use extra row/column with sentinel values
}
```

where `foundAlignmentOf(counter)` is called each alignment found (so you can use test condition depending of the size of the alignment).

Answer (score 0):

I know the rules of Bejeweled, and I can help.

The answer is easy, do a backwards if/then or select statement...

```
if (counter >= 5) matches++;
else if (counter == 4) matches++;
else if (counter == 3) matches++;
```

or

```
select (counter)
{
    case 5: matches++;
        break;
    case 4: matches++;
        break;
    case 3: matches++;
        break;
    case else: break;
}
```

You can go even higher, or even do a reverse for/do loop to check and save some code. This is merely an example...